# Haskell define multiple functions using tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples

I've just come across some Haskell code that looks something like this:

```
(functionOne, functionTwo)
  | someCondition = (10, "Ten")
  | otherwise     = (20, "Twenty")
```

From the way the code is used I *think* I understand the intent of this code i.e. it is just a more concise way of writing this:

```
functionOne
  | someCondition = 10
  | otherwise     = 20

functionTwo
  | someCondition = "Ten"
  | otherwise     = "Twenty"
```

However, I can't recall ever seeing functions written this way before and have no idea what this technique is called so can't search for any additional information about this.

So my questions are:

- Is my understanding of what is going on here correct?
- Does this technique have a name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These aren't functions, just variable bindings. You correctly understand how it works. It doesn't have any particular name, because it's just another application of pattern matching. Anytime you could declare a variable, you can declare a more complex pattern in that same position.

Comment: I would also note that the `|` notation is a separate thing called guards, which can be used at any variable or function binding.

Comment: Thanks, this clear it up for me. What confused me was a) thinking of guards as something that can only be used inside a function and b) thinking of values as functions that don't take arguments. It also doesn't help that there is no `=` between the variable and the expression when using guards. As soon as I think of this as `(variableOne, variableTwo) = if someCondition then...` it is suddenly obvious to me that this is just pattern matching.